# Using JAX-WS stub even if Apache CXF is in dependency

Tags: java, cxf, jax-ws

WS client, it works when I call my WS
when I create my stub, I get an **SEIStub** impl.

Then here is a new client for another WS in Apache CXF. We put the dependency in our pom, then bad things happen:
When I call my first WS with my JAX-WS stub I get now a `JaxWSClientProxy`, Apache CXF seems to become the default implmentation. and I cannot use my special header function that was done for WSBindingProvider instead of `JaxWsClientProxy`

Generation of client with jaxws:

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jvnet.jax-ws-commons</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${jaxws.plugin.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>wsimport</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <packageName>fr.xxxx.commons.client.stub.y</packageName>
                            <sourceDestDir>${ws.java.target}</sourceDestDir>
                            <extension>true</extension>
                            <wsdlDirectory>${project.parent.basedir}/src/main/wsdl/v2.1/</wsdlDirectory>
                            <wsdlFiles>
                                <wsdlFile>XXXXWebServices_v2.1.wsdl</wsdlFile>
                            </wsdlFiles>
                            <xnocompile>false</xnocompile>
                            <vmArgs>
                                <vmArg>-Djavax.xml.accessExternalDTD=all</vmArg>
                                <vmArg>-Djavax.xml.accessExternalSchema=all</vmArg>
                            </vmArgs>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

the JAX-WS instanciation where the error is (on the cast)

```
xStub = new XWebServicesV21(url, qnameXWebServices);

xGetPort.set(xStub.getAutogenerate());

generateHeader(aApplicationID, aUserId, (WSBindingProvider) xGetPort.get(), xUrl);
```

How to force JAXWS impl? I use JDK8 and Apache CXF 2.3.11 .

Comment: I guess you're creating the stub with wsdl2java. How you are instantiating the CXF client? Please provide code & config to understand your issue

Comment: i've added the jaxws generation and the problem where cast is no more working

Comment: I guess XwebServicesV21 is an instance of javax.xml.ws.Service, and  xStub.getAutogenerate() is the endpoint to connect with annotation @WebEndpoint. ¿Why are you using WSBindingProvider? It should be BindingProvider

Comment: yes, you're right.
we use **WSBindingProvider** to be able to do `bindingProvider.setOutboundHeaders(headers)` where headers contains an auth token.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sun's jaxws use `com.sun.xml.ws.developer.WSBindingProvider`, but CXF does not use it. `org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy` implements `javax.xml.ws.BindingProvider`

Therefore you can not cast  `xGetPort.get()` to `WSBindingProvider`. In order to add soap headers with CXF in a similar way that `WSBindingProvider.setOutboundHeaders` check [documentation](https://cxf.apache.org/faq.html#FAQ-HowcanIaddsoapheaderstotherequest/response?) or use CXF WS-Security support to generate the standard authentication headers for SOAP messages

If you want to use Sun's jaxws, make sure the jars are in the classpath before, or remove cxfjaxws dependencies.

Comment: ok so as we are wsdl first the correct approach would be to add the header in the wsdl, from the doc:
_wsdl first way: you can add elements to the message in the wsdl and then mark them as soap:headers in the soap:binding section of the wsdl. The wsdl2java tool will generate the @WebParam(header = true) annotations as above. ..._

Comment: WSDL supports the definition of headers. Also it is common to find wsdl-first approach which define the headers programmatically